# Title page bookmark suppressed by ghostscript

Tags: bookmarks, ghostscript

The MWE suggested below creates a pdf with two bookmarks, named "Title" [level 0] and below, "Section" [level 1].

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[numbered,open,openlevel=1]{bookmark}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%%
  \raggedright%
  \bookmark[named=FirstPage]{\@title}%
  {\LARGE\raggedright\bfseries\@title\par}%
  \vskip1.5\baselineskip%
  \normalfont\normalsize%
}
\makeatother

\title{Title}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Section}
\end{document}
```

When the resulting pdf is processed via ghostscript (v 9.53.3) using the command line:

```
gswin64c.exe -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dPrinted=false -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -SOutputFile="b_%%f" "%%f"
```

the "Title" bookmark above is suppressed and I cannot understand why. My question might be related to [Ghostscript 9.07: Error: A pdfmark destination … points beyond the last page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111057/371) but I am not sure exactly how.

Comment: I only have 9.50 for a test, but it looks as if ghostscript doesn't like named actions, this looks like a bug to me, they are allowed in the outline. You should report this in the ghostscript bug tracker, as a work-around you can use `\bookmark[page=1]{\@title}`. Unrelated but why on earth are you forcing OT1 encoding? At first it is the default, and at second T1 would be a better choice.

Comment: Thanks! As for the OT1 encoding, I think I observed an issue with ligatures with the T1 encoding but I might be wrong. Is this possible?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Maybe you can convert your comment into an answer that Ican accept? Thanks